# how can I minimize the code or rewrite this smaller?

Tags: javascript

I think my code can be smaller but idk how can I minimize it ?

How you would rewrite the code smaller ?

PS:

I get a JSON object and I have to find the key name from an value.

I have to found which color has the option key

exp:

```
option1: "blue"
option2: "S"
```

but if I get another request then it could be like that:

```
option1: "S"
option2: "blue"
```

so it can be reversed, so I have to find the key name from an color name

```
const getKeyByValue = (obj: _Variant, value: string) => Object.keys(obj).find(key => obj[key] === value.toLowerCase());

let k = null;

for(let i = 0; i < variants.length; i++) {
    k = getKeyByValue(variants[i], "schwarz");
      if(k) {
          break;
      }
     k = getKeyByValue(variants[i], "black");
      if(k) {
          break;
      }
    k = getKeyByValue(variants[i], "weiß");
      if(k) {
          break;
      }
     k = getKeyByValue(variants[i], "white");
      if(k) {
          break;
      }
    k = getKeyByValue(variants[i], "rot");
      if(k) {
          break;
      }
    k = getKeyByValue(variants[i], "red");
      if(k) {
          break;
      }
    k = getKeyByValue(variants[i], "gelb");
      if(k) {
          break;
      }
    k = getKeyByValue(variants[i], "yellow");
      if(k) {
          break;
      }
    k = getKeyByValue(variants[i], "grün");
      if(k) {
          break;
      }
    k = getKeyByValue(variants[i], "green");
      if(k) {
          break;
      }
    k = getKeyByValue(variants[i], "blau");
      if(k) {
          break;
      }
    k = getKeyByValue(variants[i], "blue");
      if(k) {
          break;
      }
    k = getKeyByValue(variants[i], "lila");
      if(k) {
          break;
      }
    k = getKeyByValue(variants[i], "purple");
      if(k) {
          break;
      }
    k = getKeyByValue(variants[i], "beige");
      if(k) {
          break;
      }
    k = getKeyByValue(variants[i], "pink");
      if(k) {
          break;
      }
    k = getKeyByValue(variants[i], "camouflage");
      if(k) {
          break;
      }
    k = getKeyByValue(variants[i], "gold");
      if(k) {
          break;
      }
    k = getKeyByValue(variants[i], "silber");
      if(k) {
          break;
      }
    k = getKeyByValue(variants[i], "silver");
      if(k) {
          break;
      }
```

Comment: Can multiple keys have the same value or are all values unique?

Comment: What's in `variants` ?

Comment: store all values in an array and iterate through variants would minimize the code a lot more than what you are doing

Comment: It's not really clear what the expected result of this is. Please [edit] your question with various example values for `variants` and what the expected result is for each

Comment: Why is `variants` an array? What does the found `k` value tell you without a corresponding `variants` index?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First issue I see is that you're using `Object.keys()` multiple times for the same object.

Seems you would benefit from inverting the object (swapping keys for values) then finding the first match from your array of *colours*.

```js
const variants = [
  { option1: 'blue', option2: 'S' },
  { option1: 'S', option2: 'blue' },
];

// blue is jumping the queue just for this demo
const colours = ['schwarz', 'black', 'blue' /* etc */];

let k;

for (let i = 0; i < variants.length; i++) {
  const valueMap = Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(variants[i]).map(([k, v]) => [v, k]),
  );
  k = valueMap[colours.find((colour) => colour in valueMap)];

  if (k) {
    console.log(`Found a colour in variants[${i}].${k}`);
    break;
  }
};

console.log('k:', k);
```

Caveat - this might have false-positives if any of the object values are `null`

Comment: how can I break the loop ? if the code find the key then break the loop

Comment: @managerit017 there's a `break` in the `if`

Comment: Yes but I want to say break after 1 was found so he should not find another key because if anyone send a request every color key is the same, but for each user can has a different key, but the key is everytime the same from one user so if I found an key it should stop

Comment: @managerit017 sorry, I do not understand what you're asking. If you need to provide further requirements, I suggest you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77657376/edit). Please also note that there are [several](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77657376/how-can-i-minimize-the-code-or-rewrite-this-smaller/77657425?noredirect=1#comment136907644_77657376) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77657376/how-can-i-minimize-the-code-or-rewrite-this-smaller/77657425?noredirect=1#comment136907713_77657376) asking for details on your question above

Answer (score -1):

I think this code can help you with what you need (uppercase or lowercase letters are also taken into account):

```js
const variants = [
    {"S": "blue"},
    {"R": "red"},
    {"blue": "S"}
]

function run(valueParam){
    const entries = Object.assign({}, ...variants);
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(entries)) {
        if (value.toLowerCase() == valueParam.toLowerCase()) {
            return key
        }
    }
}

let result = run("blue")
console.log(result)

result = run("red")
console.log(result)

result = run("BLUE")
console.log(result)

result = run("S")
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Try some repeated keys like `option1`, `option2`, etc in each _variant_ object and you'll see that the `Object.assign()` cannot work

Comment: @Phil If you add repeated keys, for example two objects: {"S": "blue"}

Object.assign stays with one object found, what's the use case where that doesn't work?

Comment: It actually takes the last object. Eg `Object.assign({}, {a: 1}, {a: 2})` results in `{a: 2}`